# CSS textsize & padding

Tags: html, css

I have some buttons that should all look the same.

1 contains the word "Anmäl" and the other contains "Information".
This results in the button with the longer word being bigger and i don't want that!

I want the buttons to look the same even though the words are differently long.

I'm using padding to make them bigger, i tried "width" but it dosen't work.

any help is appreciated!

CSS:

```
.startLink {
  padding: 20px;
  padding-left: 90px;
  padding-right: 90px;
  color: white;
  background: #8d68dc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #000;
  webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in;;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="index.php?anmal" class="startLink">Anmäl</a>

<a href="index.php?info" class="startLink">Information</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`width` is the answer but it's not working for you as these links are currently inline elements, which can't receive explicit width.

Give them `inline-block` or `block` for their `display` property and you can then use `width`.

As for having them the same width, just plump for a width that comfortably accommodates both. Here, for example, is how you might be center the buttons within a paragraph, each with the same width.

HTML

```
<p id='btns'>
    <a href="index.php?anmal" class="startLink">Anmäl</a>
    <a href="index.php?info" class="startLink">Information</a>
</p>
```

CSS

```
#btns { text-align: center; }
.startLink {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 .65rem;
    background: red;
    padding: 1em;
    min-width: 200px;
}
```

It's best to use `min-width` rather than `width` so that, just in case the button text (which may, in a realworld scenario, come from a database or other dynamic source) is longer than the button's width allows, it'll safely expand to accommodate it (even though this will mean your buttons are no longer the same width.)

Answer (score -2):

use "text-align:centre" instead of left padding and right padding with "min-width"
and "display:inline-block"

Comment: `centre` value!?